# Отправка данных с сайта на почту

Tags: pdf, php

Как отправить полученные данные из формы странице в формате pdf на почту?

Comment: @harley, ваш вопрос очень размыт. В текущей формулировке на него можно ответить только так: собрать все данные, сформировать PDF, воспользоваться функцией mail.

Answer (score 1):

1) Для генерации используйте FPDF или TCPDF

2) А для отправки - функция mail